# Trying to unmount Logical Volume, gives error "umount: /dev/lvm3/nlv1: not mounted"

Tags: mount, lvm, unmount

I'm fairly new to Logical Volume Management, so please bare with me. **I want to unmount the logical-volume `lvm3-nlv1`, in order to finally delete it.**

## Viewing mount point using `lsblk`

When I run `lsblk`, the following is the output I get:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1          8:1    0   549M  0 part 
├─sda2          8:2    0  49.2G  0 part 
│ └─lvm3-nlv1 253:0    0   2.3G  0 lvm  /media/theperson/97ee469c-3af3-4a2d-a6be-b86847d686ef
├─sda3          8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5          8:5    0 173.8G  0 part /
```

## Finding mount information in `/proc/mounts` using `grep`

When I tried fininding `nlv1` using grep like te following, we can see that nv-nlv1 is mounted:

```
grep nlv1 /proc/mounts
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/nv-nlv1 /media/theperson/97ee469c-3af3-4a2d-a6be-b86847d686ef ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

## Trying to Unmount Logical Volume using `umount`

I tried the following command to unmount:

```
sudo umount /dev/lvm3/nlv1       #tried even with "-v"
```

Output:

```
umount: /dev/lvm3/nlv1: not mounted.
```

**Am I missing something? I tried finding an answer on StackOverflow, but none applies to me.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct device name in the `umount`-command, it is the name you found with the previous `grep`-command:

```
sudo umount /dev/mapper/nv-nlv1
```

Alternatively you can pass the mount-point to the `umount`-command:

```
sudo umount /media/theperson/97ee469c-3af3-4a2d-a6be-b86847d686ef
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked.